# Linq to Entity delete a row from a table have no primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Q1.Can LINQ to Entity perform create, update or delete operations on a table without a primary key.??
if not then suggest me an alternate
Q2.I am not able to use DeleteObject to delete a row from a table (error::missing an assembly). What should i do to use DeleteObject.
 As an alternate to q2.(delete object) i tried
`db.check_master.Remove(checks);` (error:: Unable to update the EntitySet 'entitysetName' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation)
**Not able to access any object provided by EF like Attach,DeleteObject...etc. (Using code first with existing database approach)**

Comment: Is there any alternate i should go for? b'coz i don want to create a primary key for that needed table.

Comment: Is it possible to query a table(with no primary key) with any another query model.

Comment: But i have string type values in my column that what i used to uniquely identity a row in a table

Comment: One thing more marc I am using EF code first with existing database but the problem is i am not able to use EF object like Attch , DeleteObject...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really convenient to you if you add primary key.

Perhaps otherwise, you'll need to use `DataContext.ExecuteCommand()`.

Comment: Agree, I think not using a key on your table is going to lead to many problems with this being the first.